# sql does the query optimizer optimize foreign key references for inserts?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I need to insert into a table that references to another table (FK)
I use the following query:

```
INSERT INTO order (customer_id, price) values
    ((select customer_id from customer where name = 'John'), 12.34),
    ((select customer_id from customer where name = 'John'), 3.33),
    ((select customer_id from customer where name = 'Peter'), 5)
```

USING EXPLAIN tells me that it executes all three subqueries instead of optimizing it to use a cached result of john. How can I efficiently do this?
Do I need to get  the customer_ids in a separate query to use them later instead of using subqueries?

Or what's the best join operation to use for it?

Comment: If you have an index on `name` then you won't have to worry about performance.

Comment: @GordonLinoff so the current implementation with an index is better than using a join?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @Chris . . . There might be very slight improvements, but the index would be the major improvement.